# Why link offsetLeft considers list padding?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am reading the link element's offsetLeft attribute and changing the position of another one accordingly. However, this works as expected only without any (even browser default) styles applied to the position attributes. For example: a change in ul padding influences the li offsetLeft and results in a shift from the expected position.

```js
navbarElementsList = document.getElementsByClassName('js-element');
navbarUnderline = document.getElementById('js-underline');
let navbarElement;

for (let i = 0, len = navbarElementsList.length; i < len; i++) {
    navbarElement = navbarElementsList[i];
    navbarElementsList[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
        let underlineStart = this.offsetLeft;
        let underlineWidth = this.offsetWidth;
        document.getElementById('js-underline').style.left = underlineStart.toString() + "px";
        document.getElementById('js-underline').style.width = underlineWidth.toString() + "px";
    });
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#js-underline {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 5px;;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>
  
</head>
<body>

    <ul style=" margin-left: 40px ;">
      <li><a class="c-navbar__element js-element">aaaaaaa</a></li>
      <li><a class="c-navbar__element js-element">bbbb</a></li>
      <li><a class="c-navbar__element js-element">c</a></li>
      <li><a class="c-navbar__element js-element">ddddddddddddddd</a></li>
      <li><div id="js-underline" class="c-navbar__underline"></div></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

In the example above I changed ul margin-left to 40px and unfortunately it adds up to the final #underline position. Could anyone explain this behaviour and tell me how to implement this correctly? I would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element.offsetNNN` is relative to the its `offsetParent`, here all your elements have their `offsetParent` set to the `<body>` element.

Your `#js-underline` is also affected by that padding, or more precisely, its parent is.

So when you set that element's left to the others' `offsetLeft`, it's own `offsetLeft` is still there too.

One ugly workaround is to measure that offsetLeft when the `left` style is `0`;

```js
const navbarElementsList = document.getElementsByClassName('js-element');
const navbarUnderline = document.getElementById('js-underline');
const default_left = navbarUnderline.offsetLeft;
let navbarElement;

for (let i = 0, len = navbarElementsList.length; i < len; i++) {
    navbarElement = navbarElementsList[i];
    navbarElementsList[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
        let underlineStart = this.offsetLeft;
        let underlineWidth = this.offsetWidth;
        navbarUnderline.style.left = underlineStart - default_left + "px";
        navbarUnderline.style.width = underlineWidth.toString() + "px";
    });
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#js-underline {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 5px;;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>
  
</head>
<body>

    <ul style=" margin-left: 40px ;">
      <li><a class="c-navbar__element js-element">aaaaaaa</a></li>
      <li><a class="c-navbar__element js-element">bbbb</a></li>
      <li><a class="c-navbar__element js-element">c</a></li>
      <li><a class="c-navbar__element js-element">ddddddddddddddd</a></li>
      <li><div id="js-underline" class="c-navbar__underline"></div></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

An other would be to position the underline absolutely, so that the margin doesn't affect it anymore.

```js
const navbarElementsList = document.getElementsByClassName('js-element');
const navbarUnderline = document.getElementById('js-underline');

let navbarElement;

for (let i = 0, len = navbarElementsList.length; i < len; i++) {
    navbarElement = navbarElementsList[i];
    navbarElementsList[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
        let underlineStart = this.offsetLeft;
        let underlineWidth = this.offsetWidth;
        navbarUnderline.style.left = underlineStart + "px";
        navbarUnderline.style.width = underlineWidth + "px";
    });
}
// set to firt item
navbarElementsList[0].click();
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#js-underline {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 5px;;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>
  
</head>
<body>

    <ul style=" margin-left: 40px ;">
      <li><a class="c-navbar__element js-element">aaaaaaa</a></li>
      <li><a class="c-navbar__element js-element">bbbb</a></li>
      <li><a class="c-navbar__element js-element">c</a></li>
      <li><a class="c-navbar__element js-element">ddddddddddddddd</a></li>
      <li>
        <div id="js-underline" class="c-navbar__underline"></div>      
      </li>
    </ul>


</body>
</html>
```